# Trying to understand Cosmosdb

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to understand how to use the multi-model api for an individual cosmosdb deployment.

I launched one instance (ref attached image). I got back this url: gccosmosdb.documents.azure.com. The connection string is only for Mongodb.

Q. I need Table & Mongodb api for this db deployment. How can i get connection string for table api also within this db. Please kindly if someone could advise on how to get two api models working side by side that would eliminate 50% of my container workloads.

[image: CosmosdbURL]

Comment: In CosmosDb databases are just containers that hold collections. Collections are the actual unit of storage and API interaction. Thus I am a little confused when you talk about "db deployment". Is your goal to have one database instance that holds multiple collections each of which might use a different API? Or are you attempting to access data in the same collection using multiple APIs?

Comment: Hello @JesseCarter.

Thanks for the response. You got it right. I am trying to have one database which holds multiple collections that each uses a different API model. All collections are independent of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Today when you create a DB you are asked to choose one of the API and then all the collections in that db will follow the api. That's is true for the portal UI.

However, using the SDK ([TableSDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-sdk-dotnet), Mongo SDK) you can create two collections which hold different data models. So, if you have two collections say one with mongo data and other with documents or table. Then these two collections can be accessed independently using Mongo or Document/Table API respectively.

For Mongo you get the connection string from the portal. However for table connection string is as follows: 
[DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=MYSTORAGEACCOUNT;AccountKey=AUTHKEY;TableEndpoint=https://COSMOSDB.documents.azure.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-table-dotnet)

Hope this help.